# Create a file and access it from url angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Based on the Http response, I need to create a json file and wanted to access that file from hitting the url.

For Example,

**My URL: www.example.com**

File which was created should be accessed from www.example.com/myfile.json

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        saveAs(res, "")
      })
  }
}
```

But in the above code, file is getting downloaded on page load.

My Project link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhxlud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why you used {responseType: 'blob'} ?

Comment: just for example

Comment: if you remove it, it will work well

Comment: But how do access via url ?